# Use a value from a function into another function nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to return the value that has been declared in the first Function CreateTag and using it as variable in the second Function CreateStream, but it won't work..

I'm working with nodejs Express.
I try to use **RETURN** but it won't work..
I have tried it in differance ways, but still not work..

Can you someone help me, please?

```js
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */

//Function 1: createTag
      var createTag = function hi (TanentValue) {
          var https = require('https');
          var data = JSON.stringify({
        name: TanentValue,
        schemaPath: "Tag"
    });
    var options = {
        hostname: 'qlik_dev.be',
        path: '/meteor/qrs/tag?xrfkey=1234567890123456',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'x-qlik-xrfkey': '1234567890123456',
            'hdr-usr': 'gak\\gaka',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };

        var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        //console.log(res)

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            console.log("hi tag")
            var getResult = "GaLvAnI"; // ----> return this and use it into the function createStream
            return getResult;
        })
    })
        ;
    req.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(error)

    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
}
//Function 2: createStream
var createStream = function (TanentValue) {
    var https = require('https');
    var galvani = hi(); // --------> here I made a variable to call return value
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        name: TanentValue,
    });

    var options = {
        hostname: 'qlik_dev.be',
        path: '/meteor/qrs/stream?xrfkey=1234567890123456',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'x-qlik-xrfkey': '1234567890123456',
            'hdr-usr': 'gak\\gaka',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };

    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            console.log(galvani); // -----> use the variable here
        })
    })
        ;
    req.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(error)
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
}
//homepage
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'MCS Test' });
});
//create
router.post('/create', function (req, res) {
    //create tag
    console.log('POST / Call Create Tag');
    createTag(req.body.TanentValue);
    //create stream
    console.log('POST / Call Create Stream');
    createStream(req.body.TanentValue);

    res.send('Stream and Tag has been created');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not directly return value from async function. you have to use promise. something like this:

```js
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */

//Function 1: createTag
var createTag = function (TanentValue) { // function should be anonymouse
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var https = require('https');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      name: TanentValue,
      schemaPath: "Tag"
    });
    var options = {
        hostname: 'qlik_dev.be',
        path: '/meteor/qrs/tag?xrfkey=1234567890123456',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'x-qlik-xrfkey': '1234567890123456',
            'hdr-usr': 'gak\\gaka',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };

        var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        //console.log(res)

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            console.log("hi tag")
            var getResult = "GaLvAnI"; // ----> return this and use it into the function createStream
            resolve(getResult); // success call
        })
    })
        ;
    req.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error); // error call

    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
  });
    
}
//Function 2: createStream
var createStream = function (TanentValue) {
    createTag().then((val) => {
      var https = require('https');
      var galvani = val; // use that value from sucess call
      var data = JSON.stringify({
          name: TanentValue,
      });

      var options = {
          hostname: 'qlik_dev.be',
          path: '/meteor/qrs/stream?xrfkey=1234567890123456',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'x-qlik-xrfkey': '1234567890123456',
              'hdr-usr': 'gak\\gaka',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
      };

      var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

          res.on('data', (d) => {
              console.log(galvani); // -----> use the variable here
          })
      })
          ;
      req.on('error', (error) => {
          console.error(error)
      });

      req.write(data);
      req.end();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // handle error from createTag function here
    });
    
}
//homepage
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'MCS Test' });
});
//create
router.post('/create', function (req, res) {
    //create tag
    console.log('POST / Call Create Tag');
    createTag(req.body.TanentValue);
    //create stream
    console.log('POST / Call Create Stream');
    createStream(req.body.TanentValue);

    res.send('Stream and Tag has been created');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using just callback function or the promise.

1. Using callbacks.

```js
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */

//Function 1: createTag
var createTag = (TanentValue, callback) => {
    var https = require('https');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        name: TanentValue,
        schemaPath: "Tag"
    });

    var options = {
        hostname: 'qlik_dev.be',
        path: '/meteor/qrs/tag?xrfkey=1234567890123456',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'x-qlik-xrfkey': '1234567890123456',
            'hdr-usr': 'gak\\gaka',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };

    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            console.log("hi tag")
            var getResult = "GaLvAnI"; // ----> return this and use it into the function createStream

            callback(false, getResult);
        })
    });

    req.on('error', (error) => {
        //console.error(error)
        callback(true, error);
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
}



//Function 2: createStream
var createStream = (TanentValue, callback) => {
    var https = require('https');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        name: TanentValue,
    });

    var options = {
        hostname: 'qlik_dev.be',
        path: '/meteor/qrs/stream?xrfkey=1234567890123456',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'x-qlik-xrfkey': '1234567890123456',
            'hdr-usr': 'gak\\gaka',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };

    createTag(TanentValue, (is_error, galvani) => {
        if(err || !data){
            // do error handling...
            callback(true); // true for there was an error
        }else{
            var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

                res.on('data', (d) => {
                    callback(false);
                    console.log(galvani); // -----> use the variable here
                })
            });

            req.on('error', (error) => {
                callback(true);
                console.error(error)
            });

            req.write(data);
            req.end();
        }
    })
}


//homepage
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'MCS Test' });
});

//create
router.post('/create', function (req, res) {
    /*
    // Since the stream seems to depend on the tag created,
    // you don't need to call createTag explicitly because
    // it is always/already called from createStream.

    //create tag
    console.log('POST / Call Create Tag');
    createTag(req.body.TanentValue, function(is_error, data){
        if(!is_error){
            // do something
        }else{
            // do error handling
            console.error(error);
            res.send('Tag could not be created, please try later again..');
        }
    });
    */

    //create stream
    console.log('POST / Call Create Stream');
    createStream(req.body.TanentValue, is_error => {
        if(!is_error){
            res.send('Stream and Tag has been created');
        }else{
            res.send('Stream could not be created, please try later again..');
        }
    });

});
module.exports = router;
```

2. Using Promise

```js
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */

//Function 1: createTag
var createTag = TanentValue => {
    var https = require('https');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        name: TanentValue,
        schemaPath: "Tag"
    });

    var options = {
        hostname: 'qlik_dev.be',
        path: '/meteor/qrs/tag?xrfkey=1234567890123456',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'x-qlik-xrfkey': '1234567890123456',
            'hdr-usr': 'gak\\gaka',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

            res.on('data', (d) => {
                console.log("hi tag")
                var getResult = "GaLvAnI"; // ----> return this and use it into the function createStream

                resolve(getResult);
            })
        });

        req.on('error', (error) => {
            //console.error(error)
            reject(error);
        });

        req.write(data);
        req.end();
    })
}



//Function 2: createStream
var createStream = TanentValue => {
    var https = require('https');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        name: TanentValue,
    });

    var options = {
        hostname: 'qlik_dev.be',
        path: '/meteor/qrs/stream?xrfkey=1234567890123456',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'x-qlik-xrfkey': '1234567890123456',
            'hdr-usr': 'gak\\gaka',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };

    createTag(TanentValue).then( galvani => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

                res.on('data', (d) => {
                    console.log(galvani); // -----> use the variable here
                    resolve(d);
                })
            });

            req.on('error', (error) => {
                console.error(error)
                reject({ msg: 'request error while creating the stream', error: error})
            });

            req.write(data);
            req.end();
        })
    }).catch( error => {
        // do error handling...
        reject({msg: 'Error while creating a tag', error: error}); // true for there was an error
    });
}


//homepage
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'MCS Test' });
});

//create
router.post('/create', function (req, res) {
    /*
    // Since the stream seems to depend on the tag created,
    // you don't need to call createTag explicitly because
    // it is always/already called from createStream.

    //create tag
    console.log('POST / Call Create Tag');
    createTag(req.body.TanentValue).then( data => {
        // do something
    }).catch( error => {
        // do error handling
    });
    */

    //create stream
    console.log('POST / Call Create Stream');
    createStream(req.body.TanentValue).then( data => {

        res.send('Stream and Tag has been created');

    }).catch(error => {
        // 'Stream could not be created, please try later again..'
        res.send(error.msg);
    });

});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very handfull!! thank you it works!
But while passing the data (Json) from function 1 to function 2 with Promise, the data (json) is undefine in function 2. If I pass a data (String) from function 1 to function 2 than it works..

Why does it give me 'undefine' when it is a json?

```js
     //var id;
    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        //console.log(res)
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (data) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            var TagId = JSON.stringify(json[0]);
            console.log("2 hi getTap");
            console.log(TagId); // -------> here it works well
            resolve(TagId);
        });
    });
```

```js
        var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

            res.on('data', (d) => {
                console.log("3 hi createStream");
                console.log(galvani); // -------> here it doesn't work.. it gives me undefine

            })
        });
```

[here a printscreen of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2sAg.png)